# Dirac delta in integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to simplify the following integral

```
Integrate[ Integrate[K[x, z] u[z], {z, -Infinity, +Infinity}] K[x, y]
+ DiracDelta[x - y] u[x], {x, -Infinity, +Infinity}]
```

unfortunately Mathematica is not able to simplify it into

```
Integrate[ Integrate[K[x, z] u[z], {z, -Infinity, +Infinity}] K[x, y],
{x, -Infinity, +Infinity}]+ u[y]
```

However,

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x - y] u[x], {x, -Infinity, +Infinity}]
```

produces the correct result, namely

```
u[y]
```

I have attempted various approaches such as

```
Integrate[ Integrate[K[x, z] u[z], {z, -Infinity, +Infinity}] K[x, y]
+ DiracDelta[x - y] u[x], {x, -Infinity, +Infinity}]//Simplify
```

or

```
Assuming[Element[y, Reals], FullSimplify@Integrate[ Integrate[K[x, z] u[z], 
{z, -Infinity, +Infinity}] K[x, y]
+ DiracDelta[x - y] u[x], {x, -Infinity, +Infinity}]
```

]

but I never got the desired result.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?  `DiracDelta` has some known bugs in certain versions of Mathematica.

Comment: On further thought, this probably isn't an issue with one of those bugs.  Effectively, you want Mathematica to simplify that $\int [ f(x) + g(x) \delta(x - x_0)]\, dx$ to $\int f(x) \, dx + g(x_0)$, even if it can't evaluate the integral of $f(x)$.  My guess is that it'll be tricky to cajole Mathematica into doing this without using explicit patterns and replacement rules, and I'm not an expert on those.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am using version 10.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a custom transformation function:

```
sepint[expr_] := expr /. Integrate[Plus[a_, b_], c_] :> Plus[Integrate[a, c], Integrate[b, c]]
```

Then apply it to the expression. The `ComplexityFunction` can be used to eliminate the `DiracDelta` in the expression.

```
Simplify[Integrate[
  Integrate[K[x, z] u[z], {z, -Infinity, +Infinity}] K[x, y] + 
   DiracDelta[x - y] u[x], {x, -Infinity, +Infinity}], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {sepint}, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, DiracDelta[_], Infinity] &), 
 Assumptions -> {y ∈ Reals}]]

(*
Integrate[Integrate[K[x, z]*u[z], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]*K[x, y], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] + u[y]
*)
```